# SwiftUI hiding navigation bar affects other animations

Tags: uinavigationbar, navigationbar, swiftui

I have the following SwiftUI view and I want to have it repeat the scale animation to simulate a pulsing effect.

However, in addition to the scaling, the circle is also moving up and down. It seems like the reason is because I set navigationBarHidden to true, which causes the circle to shift down and that shifting animation repeats together with the scaling animation. Removing the navigationBarHidden line would fix the issue but I would like to hide the navigation bar.

How can I make sure the repeat animation here only applies to the scalingEffect and make sure the animation doesn't get affected when hiding the navigation bar? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@State var animate = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        .scaleEffect(animate ? 0.7 : 1.0, anchor: .center)
        .animation(Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
    }
    .onAppear {
      self.animate.toggle()
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make animation per-value on state, like

```
  Circle()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
    .scaleEffect(animate ? 0.7 : 1.0, anchor: .center)
    .animation(Animation.default.repeatForever(autoreverses: true), 
        value: animate)     // << here !!
```

Comment: Hmm just tried this and still experience the same issue where the circle would shift in position :/

Comment: I tested this as worked with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Are there any other code that might influent?

Comment: Yeah, you are right that when i tested this in a SwiftUI playground app, it seems to be working fine but only seems to be an issue with my main app which likely has other factors causing this to happen. I will debug further and add details here with new findings. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the whole view moving up and down when its child view is hidden and shown (animation) repeatedly.